# Algorithm to find kth maximum in a list using recursion

Tags: python, max

I wrote this algorithm

```
def find_max(list): 
    maximum = list[0]
    for i in list[1:]:
         if i > maximum:maximum = i
    return (maximum)
```

By using this I need recursive algorithm that finds kth maximum

Can u help me, please?

Comment: So you got this code and the task to make it resucrive? What youve got so far?

Comment: Look up introselect. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: With "kth maximum", you mean the k-th biggest number? Or the k-th occurrence of the maximum? Also, do you have to make a recursive algorithm for that that uses this `find_max` function in its current form?

Comment: can you show a recursive function that counts?